# Неправильный вывод данных C

Tags: c

Получаю вывод(-98),хотя верный вывод будет (-5).В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int  main()
{
      float t1 = 6/((sqrt(3))-2) *((sqrt(2)) + 3);
    printf("%f",t1);
}
```

```
Output:-98
```

```
Input:-5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В скобочки забыли умножение завернуть

```
float t1 = 6/ ( ((sqrt(3))-2) *((sqrt(2)) + 3) ) ;
```

Comment: Писать на сях, то что не работает на плюсах -- аморально. Правильно так: float t1 = 6.0/ ( ((sqrt(3.0))-2.0) *((sqrt(2.0)) + 3.0) ) ;

Comment: С типами всё в порядке. `sqrt(int->double)->double`. `double +- int -> double` `int / double -> double`. @lith.al Не вижу никаких проблем.

Comment: А зачем скобки вокруг `sqrt`?